# using digital certificate on pentaho

Tags: certificate, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I've to call an soap web-service onn my transformatio, but when i try make lookup the spoon throw the folow message

[image: error when I click on load button]

I've already installed the digital certificate on my machine, I have the .cer archive. I don't know how to put this certificate in my transformation.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem, too - and it's tricky to figure out.  Because PDI is a Java application, it does not play nicely with the operating system's built-in certificate management processes, or options to ignore certificate checking.  The trick is to add the certificate to a Java keystore using `keytool`

I had to solve this for Windows, so here is a PowerShell script, but you should be able to adapt the idea to shell if necessary. Also, the default password for a Java certstore is "changeit" - that's not a type-o or placeholder.

```
Param (
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory = $False,
        ValueFromPipeline = $False,
        ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $False,
        HelpMessage = 'Take action!')]
    [switch]$doit
)

## Find the JRE folders
$jre_list = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object];
$program_folders = @('C:\Program Files\Java', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java');
ForEach ($folder in $program_folders) {
    $jre_folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'jre*'};
    ForEach ($jre in $jre_folders) {
        if ((Get-ChildItem -Path $($jre.FullName) -Recurse -Filter 'keytool.exe').Count -gt 0) {
            $jre_list.Add($jre);
        }
    }
}

## Find the certificate files
$certroot = $PSScriptRoot;
$cert_files = Get-ChildItem -Path $certroot | Where-Object {$_.Name -match '^.+\.crt$' };

ForEach ($jre in $jre_list) {
    Write-Host "`n == Found JRE @ $($jre.FullName)";

    $keytool = "$($jre.FullName)\bin\keytool.exe";
    $keystore = "$($jre.FullName)\lib\security\cacerts";
    $cmd_list = "& '$keytool' -keystore '$keystore' -storepass changeit -list";
    $existing_trusts = (Invoke-Expression -Command $cmd_list).Replace('\n', '\r\n');

    ForEach ($cert in $cert_files) {
        $file = "$certroot\$cert";
        $alias = ($cert.Name).Replace('.crt', '');
        Write-Host "    >> $cert ($alias)";
        ForEach ($item in $existing_trusts) {
            $trust = $item.split(',')[0];
            if ($trust -match $alias -or $trust -match '*.my.domain.com') {
                if ($doit) {
                    ## Remove existing entries
                    Write-Host "       -- Removing entry for '$trust'";
                    $cmd_delete = ("& '$keytool' -keystore '$keystore' -storepass changeit -delete -alias $trust -noprompt").Replace("'", '"');
                    (Invoke-Expression -Command $cmd_delete -ErrorVariable stderr) 2>&1 | Out-Null
                    if (-Not $stderr) {
                        Write-Host '          Success';
                    }
                    Remove-Variable stderr -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
                }
                else {
                    Write-Host "       ++ Existing entry in keystore: '$trust'";
                }
            }
        }
        if ($doit) {
            ## Add new entries
            Write-Host "       ++ Adding entry for '$alias'";
            $cmd_add = ("& '$keytool' -keystore '$keystore' -storepass changeit -import -file '$file' -alias $alias -trustcacerts -noprompt").Replace("'", '"');
            (Invoke-Expression -Command $cmd_add -ErrorVariable stderr) 2>&1 | Out-Null
            if (-Not $stderr) {
                Write-Host '          Success';
            }
            Remove-Variable stderr -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
        }
    }
    Write-Host ' ';
}
```

Comment: @luizkava, you might be having trouble importing it due to the type.  I believe that keytool works with X.509 files, but it might prefer either text (.crt) or binary (.cer) file.  Try converting your .cer into one of these types before importing.  Also, just changing the extension to .crt or .pfx might work.  See the keytool docs for more info: 
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html

Comment: Thanks a lot friend, I'll try it